# Is it a good practice to create two different classes in one ruby script?

Tags: ruby

Is it good in practice to create two different classes in one ruby script file like this?

**Ruby file name - XYZ.rb**

```
class Car
  .........
  .........
end

class Bike
  .........
  .........
end
```

What will be the advantage or disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of multiple classes in one file is that you can quickly try something and hack stuff together. I'd suggest not doing so when coding on a more serious project or work, because as Sergio Tulentsev stated, you can get problems in environments with autoloading. Another disadvantage is that you lose track of what classes are located in what file.

Comment: Ya its will create confusion in location of class.

Comment: And I would only add, that you are the programmer, and the rule no. ω is, break all the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna give you problems if you use it in an environment with autoloading (e.g. Rails). Other than that, I don't see any technical reasons not to put more than one class in the same file. But I'd still have a file per class, just for convenience. It makes navigation easier, because "go to file" editor command is now effectively a "go to class". There are other benefits as well.

To summarize: in anything other than a script that you put together over a coffee-break, use file per class.